# Is anybody working on an ECMAScript ReDoS protection?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-next

I recently read about [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). I am curious if we will get any patch in the standard or in the JS engines like V8 for this vulnerability. Is there anybody working on it?

Comment: Why would that be something implemented in the ecmascript language? The language offers no protection against say `while(1)`, only user-agents do, I don't think it's even in the js engine that such protection are implemented. For instance in a browser, HTML event loop actually has a safe-guard concept implemented with the idea of "long running tasks", that is if a task (here a js one) takes too long, it's paused and resumed later (or killed by the user in some browsers).

Comment: Only a _fool_ would allow a user to submit a regex text (or any code text) that is to be run inside a JS. However this doesn't mean that literals submitted by users can't be searched for, right ? ... right .

Comment: @Kaiido For example adding timeout support would involve changing the standard...

Comment: @sln The problem can involve multiple languages too, for example you can search in the database based on user input and some of the databases support searching with regex, so you can end up generating regex based on user input. The question is not about that though. Working on the user input with a badly designed regex can kill the event loop too. Even a simple email validation can be problematic... Afaik. SO already went down in a ReDoS attack at least once.

Comment: But why would the standards want to implement such a timeout? The standards do not care of such issues. As I said, you can very well block any js engine by simply running `while(1){}`, and this since forever. UAs may implement some strategies to counter such case, (and e.g browsers already do) but the language has no reason to do so.

Comment: @Kaiido "e.g browsers already do" - do you have a reference for that? I am not sure you understand the problem here. While true without break is easy to catch, even your IDE can tell you that your code is bad without running it. On the other hand predicting the computational complexity of a certain regex on a certain regex engine and look for strings where it is exponential is far from trivial. I don't think there is general protection against it currently and without timeout it can casue 100% CPU and hang the event loop indefinitely.

Comment: @Kaiido Dot net already added a timeout, I guess that was not an accident either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexmatchtimeoutexception?view=netframework-4.8 For now all we can do in js to move regex execution to a separate process and kill that process by timeout. That is an ugly hax and it makes execution async.

Comment: Run that while(1){} in your console. Do you feel it was avoided at compile time or after a timeout at run time? Read HTML specs, particularly the event loop part. You'll see how browsers should already have implemented their way against this and any long running scripts.

Comment: Oh and if you really think they popped that message because while(1){} is so easy to catch, then you can try while(Math.random()>0){}